# When is it necessary to add a folder to sys.path?

Tags: python, import, packaging, setup.py

In [psycopg2's setup.py](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/master/setup.py), there is the following line:

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'scripts')
```

The *scripts* folder is in the same directory as *setup.py* - why does it need to be added to `sys.path`?

Answer (score 0):

That's something quite normal, as it allows the module to import some additional required modules which may be missing from the system. Remember that this change of sys.path is only temporary, while the setup.py is running.

Comment: I guess my question then becomes: if the folder `scripts` is **not** added to `sys.path`, is it the case that setup.py will not be able to import its contents?